# do all @configuration classes need to be specified in either getRootConfigClasses or getServletConfigClasses?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

In spring mvc project, I use purely java config style to configure the servlet container.

In a `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` subclass, I override two methods, `getRootConfigClasses` and `getServletConfigClasses`, they load beans for `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener` separately.

Do all `@Configuration` annotated classes need to be specified in either `getRootConfigClasses` or `getServletConfigClasses`, if no (probably), how and where the beans defined in those `@Configuration` classes are created and stored (in which application context)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all Configuration classes need to be specified. Remaining can be `@Import`ed in the Root or web config class

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I know using Import can form a config chain, but that also indirectly specified in those two methods. What if a config class neither specified nor Import ed in the root or web config classes? like hibernate and security config classes?